# Angular and RxJS API calls

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm new to Angular and RxJS and am having a problem making API calls.  I have been following suggestions from others I am working with but am clearly not using RxJS correctly.

On `ngOnInit()` I create a request object and call load Timeslots with arguments in the object to specify these timeslots are to be in person and not virtual.  This works fine, the code examples are below.

In `ngOnInit()`

```
let inPersonRequest = this.createRequest(this.starDate, this.endDate, "in-person", address])

this.getTimes(inPersonRequest, this.startDate, true);
```

In getTimes I have the following code

```
getTimes(timeRequest: TimesRequest, startDate: Date, displayTimeslots: boolean) {

  this.timesStore.getTimes(timeRequest).pipe(
    tap(response => {
      // @ts-ignore
      if (response != null && response.timeslots != null) {

        // @ts-ignore
        response.timeslots.forEach((ts) => {
          ts.date = new Date(ts.startTime.localTime);
          let options: Intl.DateTimeFormatOptions = {hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', hour12: true}
          ts.displayTime = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', options).format(ts.date);
        });

        if (timeRequest.location == "in-home") {
          this.inHomeTimeslots = response.timeslots;
        } else {
          this.virtualTimeslots = response.timeslots;
        }

        if (displayTimeslots) {
          let displayTimeslotsFilter = availabilityRequestMount.location == "in-home" ? this.inHomeTimeslots : this.virtualTimeslots
          this.displayTimeslots = this.timesStore.findSlots(startDate, displayTimeslotsFilter);
          if (this.displayTimeslots.length) {
            this.availabilityText = "Available appointments for " + format(startDate, 'MMM d, yyyy') + " (times are approximate)";
          } else {
            this.availabilityText = "No available appointments for " + format(startDate, 'MMM d, yyyy');
          }
        }

      }
    }),
    catchError(async error => {
      console.log('Error occurred: ', error);
    }),
    takeUntil(this.onDestroy$)
  ).subscribe()
}
```

On page render I fetch the timeslots for in home appointments.  When a user clicks on the virtual button I attempt to call the same method with a different TimeRequest but the subscription emits an event from my first call with the object that has the 'in-home' location as well as the request with the 'virtual' location.  It seems like I am approaching this incorrectly, any advice on how I can construct this differently would be appreciated.  The code that runs when the user clicks on the virtual button is below as well as the getTimes method.

```
onVisitTypeSelected(event : CustomEvent) {
    
  if (event.detail.uuid === "virtual") {
    if (this.virtualTimeslots && this.virtualTimeslots.length) {
      this.displayTimeslots = this.availabilityStore.findSlots(this.selectedDate, this.virtualTimeslots);
    } else {
      let virtualRequest = this.createRequest(this.startDate, this.endDate, 'virtual' , address);

      this.getTimes(virtualRequest, this.selectedDate, true);
    }
  } else {
      ...
    }
  }
  
}
```

```
public getTimes(timeRequest: TimesRequest): Observable<TimeResponse> {
  this.timesService.getTimes(timeRequest).subscribe({
    next: (response) => {
      if (response.status === 200) {
        const timeResults = response.body
        this.timeResponseSubject.next(timeResults)
        console.log("Time Data received: ", timeResults);
      }
    }, error: (error) => {
      this.log.error("Error occurred while fetching availability data: ", error);
      this.timeResponseSubject.next(null);
    }, complete: () => {
      console.log("Observable completed.");
    }
  });
  return this.timeResponse$;
}
```

I have changed the code a bit to not be exactly what I have in the project so minor details could possibly be incorrect but the general idea is I am using BehaviorSubjects and Observables incorrectly for what I want to achieve here.

Comment: You’ve got a lot of code here and it’s hard to tell if the methods belong to the component, service or store. It would be helpful if you could provide a minimum reproduction of your problem and possibly a StackBlitz example. From what I can see, it looks like you create a new subscription each time `getTimes` is called. So you probably have logic executed multiple times unintentionally.

Comment: I agree with the above suggestion, a working Stackblitz demonstrating *just* your issue would help us help you. And here's a video that also may help: https://youtu.be/vtCDRiG__D4 It covers some "best practices" and patterns for working with Observables.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you try to reconceive your code flow so you don't need to use `Observable.subscribe()`. Instead of subscribing and setting properties, create new observables and then use use Angular's AsynchPipe instead. Think of data flowing past and setting up pipes so the data you want elegantly comes out of the other end.

```js
/*
  Instead of subjects that _you_ have to track
  and set, it would probably be better to set
  these to FormControl values via
  FormControl.valueChanges()
  See https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#valueChanges
*/
const visitType$: Subject<'in-home'|'virtual'> = new Subject();
const address$ = new Subject();
const startDate$: Subject<Date> = new Subject(); // or maybe text and you map it to a Date?
const endDate$: Subject<Date> = new Subject(); 

constructor(timesStore: TimeStore) {
  // or this code could be in ngOnInit 

  // declared here instead of creating this object repeatedly
  const options: Intl.DateTimeFormatOptions = {
    hour: 'numeric',
    minute: 'numeric',
    hour12: true
  }; 

  /**
   * Given changes to inputs, this gets and enriches time slots
   */
  timesResponse$ = combineLatest([
    startDate$,
    endDate$,
    visitType$,
    address$
  ]).pipe(
    debounceTime(100), // wait a little so that several changes are bunched together
    map(array => this.createRequest(...array)),
    // use switchMap so that pending requests are dropped whenever new requests come in.
    switchMap(request=> this.timesStore.getTimes(request).pipe( // best if the getTimes returned value is strongly typed
      map(response => {
        const [
          startDate,
          endDate,
          visitType,
          address
        ] = request;
        response?.timeslots?.forEach((ts) => {
         ts.date = new Date(ts.startTime.localTime);
        });
        return Object.assign( // merge request with response so downstream has both
          {
            startDate,
            endDate,
            visitType,
            address
          },
          // Note: if response has any of the above properties then the returned object might not be what you expect
          response
        );
    }),
    shareReplay(1) // observables repeat their work per direct subscriber unless you use share or shareReplay.
  ); 

  this.displayTimeslots$ = timesResponse$.pipe(
    map(
      ({startDate, timeSlots}) => this.timesStore.findSlots(startDate, timeSlots)
    ),
    shareReplay(1)
  ); 

  this.displayTimeSlotsLength$ = concat(
    of(0), // until displayTimeslots$ emits its first element, the length is 0
    this.displayTimeslots$.pipe(
      map(array => array ? array.length : 0)
    )
  ).pipe(
    debounce(),
    shareReplay(1)
  ); 

// You never said why you needed these two...
  this.inHomeTimeslots$ = timesResponse$.pipe(
    filter(({visitType}) => visitType === 'in-home'),
    map(({timeslots}) => timeslots)
  ); 

  this.virtualTimeslots$ = timesResponse$.pipe(
    filter(({visitType}) => visitType === 'virtual'),
    map(({timeslots}) => timeslots)
  );
```

and then you can do things like this:

```html
<span *ngIf="displayTimeSlotsLength$ | async">
  {{displayTimeSlotsLength$ | async | number: '1.0-0'}}
  available appointments for
  {{startDate$ | async | date:'mediumDate'}}
  (times are approximate)
</span>
<span *ngIf="!(displayTimeSlotsLength$ | async)">
  No available appointments for
  {{startDate$ | async | date:'mediumDate'}}
</span>
```

The use of AsyncPipe will manage its own subscriptions. Your use of `takeUntil(this.onDestroy$)` is a best practice if you need to subscribe to things, but if you let AsyncPipe do all of the subscribing for you then you don't have to worry at all about that.

A potential "gotcha" is that if nothing downstream of observables are subscribed to then anything they emit is ignored regardless of if they pipe `shareReplay`. However, as long as the above HTML code is exposed in your template and never hidden by, say, a container with an *ngIf directive, you don't need to worry about this because `displayTimeSlotsLength$` will always be subscribed to for the life of the component and that keeps enough of the data stream active.